# Mount and unmount errors when usb is connected in 12.10.

Tags: 12.10, usb, mount, usb-drive, unmount

I just installed 12.10 and noticed some strange behaviour every time I connect a USB storage device. It reports I already have the device mounted by a different user but there is only one user account on this set up.

Here is a picture of the dialogue: [image: unable to mount]

Also when I try to mount the inserted USB drive, I have to enter gain root privileges before the device will unmount successfully. Like this:

[image: unable to unmount with without root access].

I can't copy/delete any file without root access either with the default file manager or third party file manager, `Marlin`.

How do I resolve this rather frustrating experience? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First, as root just unmount the device.  If there is a problem in the mount table this might clear it up.

As for mounting a USB, any type of mount command for devices generally requires root priv.  Once that happens, depending on the underlying permission of the USB filesystem, you still might have problems accessing it unless you are root.

Comment: It didn't help when I unmounted with as root. It seems I can't do anything else without root with every usb drive I have tried out. What's wrong

Answer (score 1):

If the drive is formatted ntfs then you need to install ntfs-3g and ntfsprogs

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g ntfsprogs;
```

It seems to be removed from the default install of ubuntu since 12.04LTS

Comment: It didn't work as I still have to gain root privileges for basic usb functions